How to fix 'Multiple video URLs' error in Google Search Console for structured data?
I am receiving the "Multiple video URLs" error in Google Search Console for the following structured data on my webpage.
How can I fix this issue and prevent Google from flagging it as multiple video URLs?
{
  "@type": "VideoObject",
  "@id": "https://www.talarkadeh.com/videos/rose-amir-garmdareh",
  "name": "فیلم عمارت رز گرمدره",
  "description": "عمارت رز گرمدره یکی از بهترین و مجلل ترین باغ تالارهای عروسی در گرمدره است که با فضایی زیبا.",
  "thumbnailUrl": "https://www.talarkadeh.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/roz-1.jpg",
  "uploadDate": "2024-01-03T09:41:08+03:30",
  "duration": "PT1M08S",
  "contentUrl": "https://www.talarkadeh.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/rose-1.mp4",
  "embedUrl": "https://www.talarkadeh.com/videos/rose-amir-garmdareh",
  "publisher": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "فیلم عمارت رز گرمدره",
    "url": "https://www.talarkadeh.com/videos",
    "logo": {
      "@type": "ImageObject",
      "url": "https://www.talarkadeh.com/wp-content/themes/tk_v2/public//icons/logo.png"
    }
  }
}


error in Google Search Console :

Multiple video URLs were identified as belonging to video:
Video URL #1
Source: Structured data
Video address (direct video URL)
Video URL #2
Source: Structured data
The address of the page showing the video.

